# What's the best three-way merge tool?

Tags: version-control, merge, dvcs

Subversion, Git, Mercurial and others support three-way merges (combining mine, theirs, and the "base" revision) and support graphical tools to resolve conflicts.

What tool do you use? Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, free or commercial, you name it.

Here's a few that I've used or heard of, just to get the conversation started:

- [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)
- [DiffMerge](http://www.diffmerge.net/)
- [P4Merge](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core-apps/merge-diff-tool-p4merge)
- [Meld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meld_%28software%29)
- Beyond Compare Pro.

(I recognize that this is sort of like the [Best Diff Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool), but it's different in that I explicitly focus on three-way merge tools; [WinMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinMerge) is off the list, for example.)

Comment: I would like to add that you can also get BeyondCompare 3 Pro for Linux (not just windows). I hope that they release an OS X version in the future.

Comment: See also [3-way XML merge algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222548) where I ask about 3-way merge of XML or HTML files.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools

Comment: Actually [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) does have 3 way comparison using it with VCS tools, you just need to pass 3 files ( left, right, result ) as arguments to the command line and it does the job.

Comment: It's difficult to say what is the best merge tool, because it depends on subjective factors. But if you are looking a feature that marks the difference, try http://www.semanticmerge.com

Comment: @Zilvinas No, Winmerge does not support 3-way merge: it doesn't have an ancestor pane.

Comment: @yoyo I heard you like comparison, so I made a comparison of your comparison tools...

Comment: CodeCompare (https://www.devart.com/codecompare/) is also promising

Comment: How can this question be closed as not constructive? It has 182 upvotes, 123 stars and 11 answers, obviously many people think it _is_ constructive.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You do know what site you were on when you posted that comment right? ;) At least they don't outright delete useful questions like these...

Comment: @HelloGoodbye StackOverflow's policy is to close opinion-based questions.

Comment: @Shuklaswag How does that relate to my question? I wondered why it was closed as "not constructive".

Comment: @HelloGoodbye This is a constructive question in its own way, but it is not constructive to building the StackOverflow Q&A knowledge base. Shuklaswag is exactly correct, but you aren't completely wrong either. Questions like these specifically should be migrated to [SoftwareRecs.SE], where it would both be constructive AND constructive to the purpose of the site. [There are already questions about this exact thing on the meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281754/constructive-non-constructive-questions) which is the appropriate place to raise these concerns, not in comments.

Comment: The copy of the link from the original post: https://web.archive.org/web/20111025085647/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool

Comment: @Dan Fabulich I suggest editing the post since WinMerge does have full-blown 3-way Merge now.

Comment: @Henrik WinMerge doesn't have 3-way merge does it? Left-Right-Base for the merge, and a result? I think I have the latest version, and it doesn't seem to have 3-way merge.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee I believe it does have 3-way merge, if I'm not completely misinformed. See this [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/GvMNFn1/winmerge-3-files.png). As you can see, I have 3 files open and can move diffs from either one of those to any other of the three. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Henrik Actually you're right. I couldn't see it because I was accessing WinMerge through Git Extensions, and it seems to be configured to launch 2-way rather then 3-way. I might see if I can fix Git Extensions to launch 3-way merge. Although I have switched to P4Merge for now -- its 3-way merge integrated with Git straight out of the box, and I quite like its UI.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee Nice. I couldn't figure out if P4Merge is paid or free. If paid, what's the price of it? Also, is there a portable version available?

Comment: @Henrik It is [free and open source](http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r20.3/doc/user/p4v_license.txt). The [release notes](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4vmergenotes.txt) have information about platforms and versions.

Comment: Araxis merge is the best tool I have ever used, but it is paid

Answer (score 187):

[KDiff3](https://github.com/KDE/kdiff3)
open source, cross platform

Same interface for Linux and Windows, very smart algorithm for solving conflicts, regular expressions for automatically solving conflicts, integrate with ClearCase, SVN, Git, MS Visual Studio, editable merged file, compare directories

Its keyboard-navigation is great: ctrl-arrows to navigate the diffs, ctrl-1, 2, 3 to do the merging.

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434482/42473

[image]

Comment: More advantages of KDiff3: same interface for Linux and Windows, very smart algorithm for solving conflicts, regular expressions for automatically solving conflicts, integrate with ClearCase, SVN and Git, editable merged file, compare directories.

Comment: integrates with visual studio too (it's possible to replace the default diff/merge tool, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx )

Comment: Does Kdiff3 have the functionality to one the list of conflicted files to navigate through them (like in any IDE, for example Idea)? I'm using Kdiff3 for resolving the Git conflicts and it's open the files one by one, but it's quite inconvenient.

Comment: @ThomasS That is not true, see the [other `kdiff3` answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2434482/42473) for an example. `kdiff3` will happily diff and merge whole directory trees and has done for many years! Some tools (such as `git`) may only launch it per file, but other tools (such as mercurial) will happily allow you to three-way diff/merge whole repositories.

Comment: KDiff3 version 0.9.95 has a bug that improperly loads some UTF-8 text, not sure when/why. KDiff3 version 0.9.98 doesn't exhibit that, but has another bug that improperly loads Unicode files that contain byte value 13 (0D) because it replaces them with 10 (0A) believing them to represent carriage returns. Looking for another free merge utility to use until something newer than KDiff3 0.9.98 is available.

Comment: KDiff3 is terrible when the local and other changes differ in the number of added lines; if locally you add lines A, B and C, but the other change only added A and C, then KDiff3 works out that A was added, then finds B conflicts with C, then adds C anyway.

Comment: Also KDiff crap is asking for sudo on Mac OS.

Comment: Does anyone have an opinion on this answer in 2016?

Comment: I have just tried both kdiff3 and p4merge for automatically resolving git conflicts. kdiff3 has the --auto feature which is invaluable for scripting. I found that p4merge's algorithm is significantly more likely to resolve a conflict without requiring manual intervention.

Comment: It doesn't supported since 2014

Comment: In terms of diff functionality, it is pretty good and it provides a good overview of diffs. It often fixes simple merge conflicts for you too.

That said, I really dislike using it. The text editor is painful. It doesn't allow basic operations like CTRL+Z or highlighting using shift+arrow keys. After all this time, I feel like I have no idea how this tool works because I keep having small and annoying issues with it, like its unwillingness to save or recognize that the merge conflict is saved.

Comment: @Shadoninja, I still a faithfully user of KDiff3 in 2020. I never found a feature good enough to make me change.

Comment: One thing bad is that development of Kdiff3 seems to have stopped since 2014. Meld is still actively being developed in 2020.

Comment: I find meld more intuitive and easier, at least when you need to make manual adjustments. Specially if you will modify more than one file.

Comment: @RuslanK. It seems still supported: https://github.com/KDE/kdiff3/graphs/commit-activity

Comment: Newer versions can be downloaded at [KDE.org](https://download.kde.org/stable/kdiff3/)

Comment: Although I like kdiff3, it is sometimes a bit stupid in detecting the correct corresponding block. Surely there must be a smarter tool.

Comment: I'm gonna check out the new version now. Sadly, I was still stuck on 0.9.8. I hope it got smarter since then.

Comment: What tool would you choose in 2021?

Answer (score 113):

Just checked out **[P4merge](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/visual-merge-tool)** since I heard about it in another blog article:

[image]

Very slick interface, and FREE!  I've been a faithful Araxis Merge user, but considering this is free and awesome, I'd encourage you to check it out.

Comment: It's available for Windows, Mac, Linux, FreeBSD, and Solaris 10

Comment: Good call, and it's one of the reasons I pay for and use Araxis Merge.

Comment: @Art: of course you can edit the merge result in P4Merge. I do it all the time!

Comment: This is simply the perfect merge tool, and it's free. For those using Visual Studio, it integrates perfectly (http://www.richard-banks.org/2009/09/using-p4merge-with-visual-studio-2008.html)

Comment: I find it is missing alot of editing functionality. And for files just around 250+ kb it is slow. (i7 quad SSD laptop) :(

Comment: p4merge is no longer available for linux? Can't find it [here](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/complete_list#ntx86).

Comment: p4merge is also not "free" for enterprise.  The license is limited for commercial use.

Comment: git integration: git config --global merge.tool p4merge; git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd "p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED". (Assuming p4merge.exe is in your path. Add -dw option to ignore whitespace.)

Comment: It's like the more graphical version of kdiff3!  Why do some prefer kdiff3?

Comment: @DH4 I just received an E-Mail from official Perforce support and P4Merge is **free for commercial use** (I work for MS, it doesn't get more enterprise than that ;))

Comment: Old post but kdiff3 has a feature advantage; mine and theirs lines can be chosen in either order.  Haven't really tested if you get more info from P4M's pretty-er line comparisons, but they do read nice.

Comment: No folder comparison support in P4merge. It would have been a really great addition to P4Merge.

Comment: kdiff3 is open source and Free Software, while P4Merge is not.

Comment: I would like to try kdiff3 but I have been unable to install without admin rights on MS Windows...

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to split conflicts into line-by-line comparisons, and there doesn't seem to be keyboard shortcuts to resolve conflicts in P4merge. Hence, it only looks good, but is severely lacking in functionality for my purposes.

Comment: Apparently P4merge is now called "Helix Visual Merge Tool". In this link it's called "Helix P4Merge and Diff Tool" but when you go to download it's the other name:  https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core-apps/merge-diff-tool-p4merge

Comment: P4Merge can also be installed with Chocolatey (`choco install p4merge`)

Comment: How does it compare to kdiff3 in 2021? Either of them smarter in auto solving conflicts?

Answer (score 106):

[Beyond Compare 3 Pro](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) supports [three-way merging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28revision_control%29#Three-way_merge), and it is a pretty impressive merge tool. It's commercial (but worth it, IMHO) and is available on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.

As pointed out in a comment, it's also inexpensive.

[image]

Note: If one does not have a merge set, that is, merge markers resident in the destination file, Beyond Compare does not offer three-way file compare/editing. Beyond Compare [says that feature is on their list](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=7834).

Note: 3-way merge is a feature in the Pro edition of Beyond Compare 3 only

Comment: It's pretty inexpensive too! (Good discounts at modest quantities)

Comment: +1 Beyond Compare is easily worth the price, especially when you consider it's other features.

Comment: Good, but no support for selecting folders

Comment: Michael, I'm not sure what you mean. Beyond Compare has great support for diffing folders: http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php.

Comment: I think three-way compare is only available in the Pro version, not the Standard one.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: It's clearly indicated on [their website](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=newfeatures) - updated answer to state Pro version is a requirement for 3-way merge

Comment: @BruceChristensen Beyond compare does not support 3Way Folder Merge even with pro version... means, you can merge file by file, but not select folders!!!

Comment: Beyond Compare 4 Pro added Folder Merge support.

Comment: Why would you use BeyondCompare over Kdiff? I'm all for paying for a good tool, I'm just not sure what makes BeyondCompare better. See also http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32594/3-way-merge-tool-for-c-sql-javascript-development-on-windows-beyondcompare-or

Comment: Does this offer anything kdiff3 does not? Why pay for this if you can get the same functionality for free?

Comment: lols what is word wrap?

Answer (score 82):

**[Meld Diff Viewer](http://meld.sourceforge.net/)**

I have had only good experiences working with Meld. I use it when I have to do messy code merges between branches. It is simple to use and has a clean interface.

- Open Source
- Linux, Windows and MacOS Supported
- Multiple File Diff
- Three-way Compare Support

In Ubuntu, install is as simple as: `sudo apt-get install meld`

[image]

Comment: +1  Meld is slick, clean, "just enough" software.

Comment: Just gave meld a spin to diff/merge two branches, was almost perfect except for a SVN created false WS

Comment: @aib could you please elaborate?  In what way is it flawed/misleading?  I just did hg merge --tool=meld and I found it quite satisfactory.

Comment: @Aryeh Leib Taurog: I don't remember. I think it was something like text missing in A (as compared to B) showing up in A (as "missing") instead of in B (as "extra"). You may very well have found your one-time experience satisfactory; I have done the same at one time or another with all the available merge tools in Ubuntu. But one does not appreciate a really good merge tool until one tries to do a 3-way merge for their coworkers, on a codebase one knows nothing about. *Then* it becomes crucial whether you can tell what belongs where at a glance.

Comment: Meld, unfortunately, is *NOT* three-way merge tool (even they state it on the homepage). For three-way merging you need _FOUR_ windows (the base file). But I love meld, works great.

Comment: Meld doesn't run out of the box in Windows. More info here https://live.gnome.org/Meld/Windows

Comment: @lzap, actually meld *was* three-way, but it was undocumented and a month or so ago I noticed they've completely removed the 3-way merge: http://is.gd/prKX5d If you stick with an old enough version you are still in luck though.

Comment: Interesting... thats unfortunate :-(

Comment: Fantastic app. This is also the only light weight graphical three way compare tool I have found that does force you into merge mode. Exactly what I was looking for with my present upgrade project. I'm moving away from UltraCompare to Meld effective immediately :)

Comment: Meld now runs out of the box on Windows. It looks great, however it's diff tool isn't as smart as BeyondCompare, KDiff3, and DiffMerge.

Comment: @yoyo: `Meld doesn't run out of the box in Windows.` Meld 3 now runs on Cygwin.

Comment: Just tried it in Windows. It runs out of the box but has numerous UI flaws (opening context windows in the wrong place of the screen, cumbersome file/directory chooser, etc.)

Comment: I have experience with Kaleidoscope, Meld, KDiff3, vim difftool and a handful of others. Honestly, at least at the moment, on the Mac, I find Meld is perfect. Sure, it's not the fanciest of applications, but it does an excellent job.

Comment: As of today, Meld supports 3way diff reliably for quite a while, and also runs out-of-the-box on Windows for quite a while (other than indicated in earlier comments). The glitches that were described in comments are (hopefully, at least in my experience) a thing of the past as well.

Answer (score 60):

vimdiff.  It's great.  All you need is a window three feet wide.

[image]

Comment: Took some time to figure out that you can do "gvimdiff -O branch1.txt base.txt branch2.txt merge.txt" and the use ctrl+w J to move the merge buffer to the bottom of the screen. Is this how you use it?

Comment: Pretty much, except I use vim, not gvim.

Comment: downvote, it doesn't really resolve conflicts, it's just diff.

Comment: vimdiff now has nice git handling for 3-way merging (ie 4 panes) - http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/A_better_Vimdiff_Git_mergetool#Vimdiff_for_three-way_merges

Comment: @piotr vimdiff does indeed resolve conflicts. You use the command "diffg <bufferNum>" to build the merged file in the bottom pane. The buttom merge pane is buffer 1 the others are 2,3,4 across the top. To jump to diffs use [c and ]c. This is out of the box functionality on debian wheezy 7.7.

Comment: 3 feet wide? They don't sell screens in that size over here.

Answer (score 38):

[Source Gear Diff Merge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/):

Cross-platform, true three-way merges and it's completely free for commercial or personal usage.

[image]

Comment: diffmerge is quite nice, though it takes a while to start up.

Comment: I've used DiffMerge for years and liked it.  However, I read [this](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/05/11/perforces-p4merge-file-comparison-editor-a-review/) blog post where the author was looking at diff-merge tools and whittled down the list to DiffMerge and P4Merge.  He ended up going with P4Merge simply because it had a nicer interface.  I've just started using P4Merge today and I would have to agree.  In particular, DiffMerge does not show changes well - it shows them as a deletion and insertion.  This can be confusing if there are many changes close together.  P4Merge displays it better.

Comment: I see that diffmerge is [not free](https://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/register), it costs $19

Comment: @erkfel, That is incorrect. Registration is optional and the software is free to use: "SourceGear DiffMerge is an award-winning file diff and merge tool that has been helping professional developers and hobbyists since 2007. SourceGear DiffMerge is licensed for use free of charge. However, by registering DiffMerge you will help fund new product development, maintenance, and support. 
As a way of thanking our registered users and encouraging additional registrations, we have added some new features in 4.2..." (in program text)

Comment: @SimonTewsi Things to have reversed. P4Merge displays moved lines as a deletion and insertion, whereas DiffMerge properly shows it as being moved. So as of right now from my testing, DiffMerge is actually better than P4Merge.

Comment: One thing I find useful in DiffMerge, compared to P4Merge (which I now use for diffing and merging in git), is that it integrates with Windows File Explorer.  In particular, I can remember a file in one folder, then compare the remembered file to another in a different folder.  I find this useful maybe once or twice a month, where I don't have to move two files into the same folder to compare them (eg SQL scripts not under source control).

Comment: @SimonTewsi: P4Merge  for Mac does not require that files be in the same folder. It allows you to browse the file system and select base, first, and second files from anywhere on the computer.

Comment: @SteveSamuels: Good to know, I'll see if it works with P4Merge for Windows as well. Thanks.

Comment: No longer being developed/updated since 2013.

Answer (score 35):

Kdiff3 conflict resolution algorithm is really impressive and it nicely integrates with Git.

I recommend to configure it as [Git mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308482/how-can-i-configure-kdiff3-as-a-merge-tool-and-diff-tool-for-git?rq=1) or to use a nice Git frontend as [GitExtensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/).

Even when Git/Subversion indicates a conflict, Kdiff3 solves it automatically. There's versions for Windows and Linux with the same interface. It is possible to integrate it with Tortoise and with your linux shell. Side note: you can also experiment with [Git merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies)

It is in my list of favorite open source software. One of the first tools I install in any machine.

You can configure it as the default diff tool in Subversion, Git, Mercurial, and ClearCase. It also solves almost all the ClearCase conflicts. In Windows, it has a nice integration with windows explorer: select two files and right click to compare them, or right click to 'save to later' a file, and then select another one to compare.

The merged file is editable, so you can fine tune after merge conflicts. Has slick keyboard shortcuts.

You can also use it compare and merge directories. See:
[image: Kdiff3 Comparing directories]

An advanced feature is to use regular expressions for defining automatic merges.

My only annoyance is that it is a little difficult to compile if it isn't present in your favorite distro repository.

Comment: I agree about the merge algorithm.  It is incredible sophisticated, and strangely seems to "know" what you want to do in a way that other tools cannot.  It regularly crushes diff3 and Subversion (blarg), and can even be helpful with a Git merge.

Comment: where are the keyboard shortcuts to goto next and choose a/b/c?

Comment: @mylord : use  a small Auto-Advance-delay and the shortcuts Ctrl-1/2/3 to select A/B/C for many conflicts.

Comment: has anything replaced KDiff3 for you? Big user of it, but I find myself seeing if there is a better alternative these days

Comment: @chrispepper1989, I still use KDiff3 in Git today. I've never found a 3 way merge app that's significantly better than KDiff3. P4Merge has a more modern interface, but when I tested it you couldn't edit the merged file (I think you can do it now).

Comment: Thanks :) I found out that kdiff was being slow due to a weird quirk from a new security tool we have now, so I'm happily back to using kdiff :) sometimes I use meld to see the directory impact

Comment: @neves: P4Merge allows editing the merged file.

Answer (score 33):

[Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/). It is commerical, but it is so worth it... It is available for Windows and the Mac OS X.

[image]

Comment: Agree, it's the best I've used.

Comment: My observation: Its relatively slow when handling large files around 5MB.

Comment: +1 for Araxis.  One of the few tools I was willing to pay good money to have for personal use.  Everything else is cluttered, confusing, and pales in comparison (pun intended).

Comment: After using Araxis for a long time my company has switched to KDiff3 for the following reasons:

(1) When a merge in Araxis is cancelled the file still gets marked as resolved in TortoiseHg.

(2) Araxis shows a mixture of the base revision & the merge result in the "Merge Result" pane which is frequently confusing.

(3) From TortoiseHg KDiff3 will automatically merge without user interaction if it can do so.

(4) KDiff3's merge algorithm just seems to do a better job.

However we still use Araxis as our compare tool :)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments for other answers, a proper 3-way merge tool has 4 panels - base, local, remote and _result_. Araxis conflates base and result, which can lead to problems.

Answer (score 17):

I love [Ediff](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/EdiffMode). It comes built-in with [GNU Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs).

To do a three-way diff, use `ediff-files3` (for selecting three files) or `ediff-buffer3` (for selecting three already-open buffers). You'll get a screen looking like this:

[image: three-way diff in emacs]

*Note the word-difference higlighting.*

You can hit `n` or `p` to go to the next/previous diffs, while `ab` will copy the region from buffer a (the leftmost one) to buffer b (the middle one), and similarly for other two-letter combinations of `a`, `b`, `c`; `rb` will restore the region in buffer b. Hit `?` for a quick help menu, or [read the fine manual on diff3 merging in Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/Merging-and-diff3.html).

Comment: As much as I love ediff, I see only two buffers above... a 3-way merge is supposed to have 3 or 4 windows: the three being merged (local, remote and their common ancestor base), and the final merge output. There *does* seem to be a 3-way merge in ediff (called `ediff-merge-with-ancestor`) but I'm not sure if it has 3 panes or 4, and also the screenshot above doesn't reflect that.

Comment: Edited to show a three-way diff @ShreevatsaR

Comment: @unhammer Thanks this is better, but it still only shows 3 windows so it's not clear that it's a true 3-way diff (which would have 4 windows; see the kdiff3 and other examples). If what's shown in the screenshot are the three things being merged, where is the output?

Comment: You destructively modify one (or more!) of the buffers. That's why I mentioned that `ab` will copy the region from buffer a to buffer b. 

I don't think there's a four-window version of `ediff` yet. (I know `emerge` uses a dedicated output buffer instead, but `emerge-files-with-ancestor` doesn't *show* the ancestor, only [uses it to guess the correct version](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Overview-of-Emerge.html#Overview-of-Emerge) by seeing which one agrees with the ancestor.)

Answer (score 13):

[Ultracompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare.html). It is really good, handles large files (more than 1 GB) well, is available for Windows/Mac/Linux, and it's commercial, but it is worth it.

[image: Screen shot of UltraCompare Professional on Windows]

Comment: I don't know how to set it to support 3-way merging... Can it display a base file in the middle, 2 changed files at left and right, so I can see what are changed in both files based on the base file and have the merged result of 2 changed files in at bottom? I'm using UltraCompare 17.0

Comment: A bit of googling found this https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultracompare/block-line-mode-merge.html - talks about 3 way merging in the step 6 advanced merge.

Answer (score 12):

[Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) is an easy to use three-way merge tool.  It supports all of the platforms and version control systems you mentioned, and it can compare more than three files at the same time.

[image]

Comment: And it even supports comparing N files at the same time! This comes handy if you need to compare config files from many homogenous applications.

Comment: I use Diffuse for my more than three file compares

Answer (score 6):

[xxdiff](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/) if you're in Linux land.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The summary is that I found ECMerge to be a great, though commercial product. http://www.elliecomputing.com/products/merge_overview.asp

[image]

I also agree with MrTelly that Ultracompare is very good. One nice feature is that it will compare RTF and Word docs, which is handy when you end up programming in word with the sales guys and they don't manage their docs correctly.

Comment: The first link isn't working, it returns 500 error. If the resource has been moved, please adjust url.

Comment: @SergeyP.akaazure - sorry about that. My blog is defunct - I've removed the link..