# iPhone version control tools (subversion)

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control, filemerge

I've used iPhone SDK and tools for several months. Xcode seems pretty nice, but there is one tool which I don't get: **FileMerge**. How can anyone use it for comparing files or doing merge?

Seriously now, **what do you really use?**

My use case is **subversion** database on remote server, few local developers working on same project as well as few remote developers. Cannot call/talk each person separately to ask what did they do, must have usable file/folder diff/merge tool. Looking for graphical version control front-end, which integrates nicely with Xcode.

I would prefer [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) myself, been happy user for years, but it wasn't available for Mac OS X yet.

Comment: I’ve always liked FileMerge. I’ve tried several other diff/merge viewers, and I just keep coming back to FileMerge. Granted, it’s 10 years later, but I don’t know why you don’t like it...

Comment: ...unless you were trying to use it as a general SVN GUI, which is not what it’s for. (At that time, I was using Diffly and svnX for that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We chose [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) for now. My more experienced colleague checked several Mac apps and chose that one based on its merge feature. Thanx for recommendations nevertheless!

Comment: Hmph, system complains I have not selected correct answer. Don't want it bug me about that, but the problem is "correct answer" for me was not any of the proposed ones. Have to choose this one, even when I feel it's right to choose your own answer. Sorry, everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I know you are probably looking for a XCode based answer/solution. But here is what I do:

Everytime I must do a merge, I launch [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) which has a nice [SVN plugin](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) that will do merges decently. If you have some experience in Eclipse platform you will have no problems in setting this up. Otherwise, you might want to do a little bit of reading on how to install plugins on Eclipse platform.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got by with FileMerge for a while but it's not great, I agree.

Now I uses [Changes](http://bitbq.com/changes/), which I recommend.

If you're using SVN I'd also highly recommend [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) as an SVN client.

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer tkdiff for two-way merge, there are several utilities available especially for mac:

- [Araxis](http://www.araxis.com/merge_mac/index.html)
- [DeltaWalker](http://www.deltopia.com/compare-merge-sync/macosx/)

And there is a generic [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572237/whats-the-best-three-way-merge-tool) about three-way merge tools.