# 3-way XML merge algorithm

Tags: xml, xhtml, merge, diff

I want to be able to do a 3-way merge of XHTML documents:

1. Start with some original copy of the document
2. One user edits a copy of the original document
3. Another user edits a separate copy of the original document
4. Need a tool to merge (automatically and/or visually) the changes made by the two users.

Note:

- I want to include this functionality in commercial software: so I prefer something that's free-as-in-beer and/or open source, instead of a commercial tool.
- I suspect it's better if the tool is XML-aware, than to try to use software like `diff3` which implements 3-way merge of flat text
- Given that all three input documents are valid XHTML documents, the resulting output document should validate too

Tools I've found include:

1. [The "3DM" XML 3-way Merging and Differencing Tool](http://tdm.berlios.de/3dm/doc/index.html)
2. [Fuego Core XML Diff and Patch Tool](http://code.google.com/p/fc-xmldiff/wiki/HomePage)
3. XmlDiff (lately from the GotDotNet site which has been shut down, but maybe it's living on as a component of [XML Notepad](http://xmlnotepad.codeplex.com/))

The first of the above (i.e. "3DM") says explicitly that it implements 3-way merges.

I don't know about the other two: whether "diff" followed by "patch" is equivalent to a 3-way merge, or instead whether "patch" can only reapply the diff to the original file (and not to a third, altered copy of the file)

Can you recommend some software (from the list above, or elsewhere) for this purpose, and/or a description of a merge algorithm?

---

Edit: [Matching, diffing and merging XML](http://useless-factor.blogspot.com/2008/01/matching-diffing-and-merging-xml.html) is another article from 2008, which includes a brief survey of various algorithms and references to various implementations.

---

Edit #2: The author confirmed that the Fuego Core XML Diff and Patch Tool can only patche the original file, and doesn't implement 3-way merging.

Answer (score 4):

I can add to your collection [DeltaXML](http://www.deltaxml.com/) - they do not claim diff3, but worth considering.

Comment: Thanks: they introduce their 3-way merge for XML at http://www.deltaxml.com/dxml/products/sync/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a free solution, I'm afraid, but [Project: Merge](http://www.projectmerge.com) is a cheap XML comparison and merge tool which can be controlled through the command line.  It could probably plug straight in to your application.

Comment: It may not be free but at €19 per license it may as well be. A neat little tool and no they're not paying me to say that :)

Comment: This is the best tool out there that I've seen.  Though, they have updated it and renamed it `Oso XML Merge`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One free alternative would be to do

```
$ xmlstarlet fo before.xml > before.xml
$ xmlstarlet fo after.xml > after.xml
```

and then do

```
$ diff before.xml after.xml
```

to create a patch of the XML difference. It's free and simple.