# Convenient diff of patch files in Gerrit

Tags: patch, gerrit

My team using Gerrit for reviewing of changes and sometimes we have to push .patch for some files. Sometimes these .patches could reach over ~1000 lines (which obviously not good for reviewing). It is very inconvenient to review it as diff between patches itself. It would be better(in some cases) to review it as diff of origin file and origin file with applied patch(not diff between .patches). Even if original file isn't under version control, committer could attach it with patch set, right?

Unfortunately, after lasting googling i didn't find anything...
Is there any way to show diff between two patch files (not patch sets) in such approach or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is to find a [three-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572237/whats-the-best-three-way-merge-tool) tool to compare

- the original source;
- the source with the old patch; and
- the source with the new patch.

To use such a tool, I think you'd need to use the command lines the Gerrit interface provides to fetch the changes locally, then apply the patches, then use the merge tool for the review.

I don't think you'll find a way to get a "three-way merge" view of the code in the Gerrit UI itself.