# SVN merge tool GUI

Tags: svn

my team is using svn for version control.
Part of my daily job is to merge the dev branch code to trunk by executing two or three scripts manually. Is there any good SVN GUI or tool to do these studff

Comment: Tool suggestion requests are explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow -- see entry #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" section of http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows: https://tortoisesvn.net/index.de.html

If you are using *nix: http://www.rapidsvn.org/

Or platform independent: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

But anyway, for software recommendations please use: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I have good luck using tortoiseSVN:
https://tortoisesvn.net/

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** "SVN GUI" in common, it's any [three-way merge tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572237/whats-the-best-three-way-merge-tool), which you can use with SVN (in any GUI or even in console SVN - see `--diff3-cmd` option of `svn merge` or `merge-tool-cmd` parameter in `config` file)